# Do rockets or destroyed systems count for the green d8?

Tags: mobile-frame-zero

From [Mobile Frame Zero *Rapid Attack*](http://mobileframezero.com/mfz/), page 64:

> A mobile frame with neither direct fire nor artillery range weapon systems get 1 green 8-sided die as well. This doesn't count as a system and can't be destroyed.

And from page 65:

> In addition to its frame and systems, a mobile frame can also carry up to 3 single-shot rockets.
>
> A single-shot rocket provides 1 red d8 at direct fire range, once only. Discard it after you use it.

And from page 123:

> When a mobile frame takes damage:
>
> For each damage it takes, it loses one system. Its owner chooses which system it loses. Pop it off the frame and drop it on the field. Since that system's gone, it doesn't provide its die or dice in any future turns.

This leads to the following questions:

- If I make a melee mech with all of its red dice devoted to a claw attack (hand-to-hand range), can I put a rocket on my mech and still get the green d8 movement bonus? Even when I'm firing my rocket?
- If my mech *had* a gun, but it got blown off so now it doesn't anymore, do I get the green d8 movement bonus for my last big dramatic charge? Or am I a sitting duck on the battlefield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I make a melee mech with all of its red dice devoted to a claw attack (hand-to-hand range), can I put a rocket on my mech and still get the green d8 movement bonus?

Yes.  Since **Single Shot Rockets don't count as systems**, the bonus Green d8 for having no ranged weapons ignores them.

> Even when I'm firing my rocket?

Yes.  (See above.)

> If my mech had a gun, but it got blown off so now it doesn't anymore, do I get the green d8 movement bonus for my last big dramatic charge?

Yes.  **Once you have no ranged weapon systems left you gain the bonus Green d8**.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond, and welcome to the site! (I added some quote blocks to your answer. Hope you don't mind.)